# Combine multiple push messages for the same app

Tags: android, push-notification

**Current state:**
If the user receives multiple push messages for the same app, then each message will have one entry.
See the screenshot attached for an example with many push messages.

[image]

**Expected:**
Check if there is a way to combine the messages for the same app. The app name should be shown once and below the Text for each push message. Each push should be clickable so that the user will end up on the correct item data

Can anyone please help me to resolve?

Comment: what was your effort?code?

Comment: I need an example or tell me your solution to custom push message, just the idea

Comment: @DatNguyen have you found any solution?

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed: Android does not support to make it

Comment: @DatNguyen then how whats app is doing?

Answer (score 1):

Collapsing your notification into one notification normally means you lose the ability to click each individual notification.
What you could do is add an [action](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Actions) for each added notification. This way the expanded view would list all your individual notifications preserving the ability to click all of them individually.

It's not something users will be used to though.

Answer (score 1):

I think `Notification.InboxStyle` should help.

Check it out. Here is the document: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.InboxStyle.html